# Error during modelCompile() [OpenBUGS]

Tags: r, bayesian, openbugs

I am trying to do Bayesian NHST between two groups. Each group consists of many variables, and  in order to avoid multiple hypothesis corrections I opted for Bayesian method. However my code in OpenBUGS is giving the following error:

```
"Error in handleRes(res) :
Internal "trap" error in OpenBUGS, or non-existent module or procedure called."
```

I am using BRugs R-package with `modelCheck(...)` - model is syntactically correct and with `modelData(...)` - data loaded are appearing but when tried to compile with `modelCompile(..)` error pops up. I am quite new to the OpenBUGS.

What does this error mean??

Answer (score 0):

This means that OpenBUGS has crashed - it's not your fault, but the program's fault for not giving a proper error message.   The Windows interface would be slightly more, but not much more, informative than the R interface in this circumstance, and give a "trap" window.   The [OpenBUGS manual](http://openbugs.info/Manuals/TipsTroubleshooting.html#TrapMessages) gives some hints on why this might happen and possible solutions.